# Nested while loops in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a grid of stars with a nested **while** loop.

It does work with a **for** loop:

```
for(m = 1; m <= 5; m++) {
    for(n = 1;n <= 10; n++) {
        document.write("*" + " ");
    }
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

but I can't figure out how I can solve it with a while loop:

```
while(m <= 5) {
    while(n <= 10) {
        document.write("*" + " ");
        n++;
    }
    document.write("<br>");
    m++;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Thnx

Comment: Well, did you declare and initialise `n` and `m` anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the initializers. `m` needs to start and `1`, and `n` needs to *restart* at `1` every time `m` is incremented.

```
var m, n;
m = 1;
while(m <= 5) {
    n = 1;
    while(n <= 10) {
        document.write("*" + " ");
        n++;
    }
    document.write("<br>");
    m++;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to post the initializers :p
But I didn't know that I had to restart n.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not reset the n variable, so everytime it is 10 and thus not entering the while loop. You need to do:

```js
var m = 0,
    n = 0,
    div = document.getElementById('draw');

function writeToDiv(stringToWrite) {
  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + stringToWrite;
}

while (m <= 5) {
  while (n <= 10) {
    writeToDiv("*" + " ");
    n++;
  }
  n = 0;
  writeToDiv("<br>");
  m++;
}
```

```html
<div id="draw">

</div>
```

Comment: No need to reset `n` twice at both ends of outer loop